# Returning a value from a dictionary in a function in Swift

Tags: swift, function, dictionary, option-type

I'm currently learning optionals in swift from one of Apple's iBooks and am having a bit of an issue with an exercise. These are the directions:

> Imagine you are creating an app for making purchases. Write a function that will take the name of an item for purchase and will return the cost of that item. In the body of the function, check to see if the item is in stock by accessing it in the dictionary stock. If it is, return the price of the item by accessing it in the dictionary prices. If the item is out of stock, return nil. Call the function and pass in a String that exists in the dictionaries below. Print the return value.

```
var prices = ["Chips": 2.99, "Donuts": 1.89, "Juice": 3.99, "Apple": 0.50, "Banana": 0.25, "Broccoli": 0.99]
var stock = ["Chips": 4, "Donuts": 0, "Juice": 12, "Apple": 6, "Banana": 6, "Broccoli": 3]

func costOfItem(item: String) -> Double? {
    var names = stock.keys
    var amount = stock.values

    for (names, amount) in stock {
        if amount == 0 {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
costOfItem(item: "Chips")
```

I don't really know where to go from here. Optionals has been a very confusing unit for me in this book. I know that I have to return a price, which will be a double. I just don't know how to go into the prices dictionary and extrapolate it and return it. I tried a few methods from searching online (using .contains method, comparing strings) and all I got were errors. Can someone please walk me through this exercise? I really want to understand this topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a loop. And you don't need those first pair of `names` and `amount` variables. Simply get the number of stock using the `item` name. If not zero, get the cost from the `prices` dictionary.

```
var prices = ["Chips": 2.99, "Donuts": 1.89, "Juice": 3.99, "Apple": 0.50, "Banana": 0.25, "Broccoli": 0.99]
var stock = ["Chips": 4, "Donuts": 0, "Juice": 12, "Apple": 6, "Banana": 6, "Broccoli": 3]

func costOfItem(item: String) -> Double? {
    if let available = stock[item] {
        if available == 0 {
            // none available
            return nil
        } else {
            // return the price
            return prices[item]
        }
    } else {
        // unknown item
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: I have this terrible habit of overcomplicating things when it comes to using code. Thank you so much for simplifying it for a beginner like me!

Answer (score 1):

If you can avoid the if/then/else...logic type walk and make your functions pure, which means you can't just 'grab' data from outside, it must be passed in.

```
  func costOfItem(item: String) -> ([String:Double], [String:Int]) -> Double? {
    return { prices, stock in
      guard let itemCount = stock[item],
        itemCount > 0 else { return nil }
      return prices[item]
    }
  }
```

Code will get a lot smaller/cleaner, code will be abstracted from any actual data and functions can be tested 100%!

```
  var prices = ["Chips": 2.99, "Donuts": 1.89, "Juice": 3.99, "Apple": 0.50, "Banana": 0.25, "Broccoli": 0.99]
  var stock = ["Chips": 4, "Donuts": 0, "Juice": 12, "Apple": 6, "Banana": 6, "Broccoli": 3]

  costOfItem(item: "Chips")(prices, stock) // 2.99
```

This function takes an item:String then immediately returns another closure that expects the data of (prices:[String:Double], stock:[String:Int])...which is passed in by the second bracket calling the returned function.

```
  XCTAssert(costOfItem(item: "Chips")(prices, stock) == 2.99, "Test failed to find correct price for 'Chips' - 4 in stock!")
```